# Is it possible to connect a Drobo to a Terastation

Tags: backup, raid, storage, drobo

I have a terastation which has 2x USB inputs for connecting external hard drives or USB printer to, and I want to know if I could connect a Drobo to one of those USBs to effectively put the Drobo on the network?

I know Drobo sell the Drobo FS which has ethernet - but it's pretty damn expensive!

(FYI - All running on gigabit home network, used mainly for video/music streaming along with regular document file storage. Currently terastation has 4tb. Windows7 computers and various phones/tablets/games consoles access the data - but mainly the PCs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly someone on the Buffalo forum said that the max size USB HDD the terastation can take is 3tb, and that only the 1st HDD in the drobo would show up :-(